# HTML Creating variable URLs

Tags: html, django, object

I've been banging my head against the wall for a while now on this problem. Here is what I'm doing: Creating a Django website that populates different pages with Twitch livestreams. It's a learning project to use API in a web application.

I have built a models Class Stream:

```
...
class Stream(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    channel = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    ...
```

Now I pass that info to my views.py

```
...
def media(request, media_id):
    specificMedia = get_object_or_404(Stream, pk=media_id)
    channel = str(specificMedia.channel)
    return render(request, 'livestream/media.html', {'specificMedia': specificMedia, 'channel': channel})
```

finally this reaches my template which looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#B0B0B0">

<p>Media Title: {{ specificMedia.name }}</p>
<p>Date: {{specificMedia.pub_date}}</p>
<p>Channel: {{channel}}</p>

<p><div id="urldata">content</div></p>


<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
    height="378" 
    width="620" 
    id="live_embed_player_flash" 
    data= <div id="urldata">content</div>
    bgcolor="#000000">
  <param  name="allowFullScreen" 
      value="true" />
  <param  name="allowScriptAccess" 
      value="always" />
  <param  name="allowNetworking" 
      value="all" />
  <param  name="movie" 
      value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" />
  <param  name="flashvars" 
      value= <div id="urlvalue">content</div>
</object>

<script>
    var data = "http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=" + {{channel}};    
    document.getElementById('urldata').innerHTML = urldata;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now here is my difficulty. I can get `{{channel}}` to display the correct twitch channel, but when I try to make the URL strings in the Object for the twitch API everything falls apart. If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong here, but are you sure the paragraph tags (<p>) are supposed to be in the document's header?

Comment: @feaDawn Correct, but I changed them (my code and question) and there was no major change. The site still looks and preforms the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<script>
    var data = "http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=" + {{channel}};    
    document.getElementById('urldata').innerHTML = urldata;
</script>
```

To

```
<script>
    var data = "http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel={{channel}}";    
    document.getElementById('urldata').innerHTML = urldata;
</script>
```